# A procedure to Bulk Copy a Very Large Table to multiple csv files by passing date as parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a procedure to Bulk Copy a Very Large Table to multiple csv files by passing date as parameter

**Example csv output:**
 Jan2006Sales.csv,  Feb2006Sales.csv ...

The name of the output cvs file do not matter as long as it chunks the extract by date.

I have this:

```
@StartDate = '2015-01-01'
@EndDate   = '2015-01-31'

DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [DB_DATAWAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SALES_TBL] where  Sales_date  >= @StartDate and Sales_date  <= @EndDate" '
+ 'queryout \\Salesasv\Saldw$\Ounbound\Jan2005Extract.csv -c -t| -T -S'
+ @@servername
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
-----
@StartDate = '2015-02-01'
@EndDate   = '2015-02-31'
--
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [DB_DATAWAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SALES_TBL] where  Sales_date  >= @StartDate and Sales_date  <= @EndDate" '
+ 'queryout \\Salesasv\Saldw$\Outbound\Feb2005Extract.csv -c -t| -T -S'
+ @@servername
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: the code looks ok. basically. what is the problem? does it not deliver the expected result, throw an error, ...? you could put the repeating part in a stored procedure and call that multiple times, maybe in a loop, depending on requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop on the date parameters, and some dynamic SQL does the trick.

```
DECLARE @date_from DATETIME='20150101';
DECLARE @date_to DATETIME='20151231';

DECLARE @eom DATETIME;
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000);

WHILE @date_from<=@date_to
BEGIN
    SET @eom=EOMONTH(@date_from);
    SET @query=
        N'SELECT * '+
        N'FROM [DB_DATAWAREHOUSE].[dbo].[SALES_TBL] '+
        N'WHERE Sales_date>='''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@date_from,112)+''' AND Sales_date<='''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@eom,112)+'''';
    SET @cmd=
        N'bcp ' +
            N'"'+@query+'" ' +
            N'QUERYOUT "\\Salesasv\Saldw$\Ounbound\'+LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,@date_from),3)+DATENAME(YEAR,@date_from)+'Extract.csv" ' +
            N'-c -t| -T -S';
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
    --PRINT @cmd;

    SET @date_from=DATEADD(MONTH,1,@date_from);
END
```

Comment: Thank you TT. It looks perfect except that it gives data conversion error:   "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: @softgi I just ran this on [Rextester](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler), without any errors whatsoever (with the print command uncommented, and the exec statement commented out).

Comment: Hi Thank you. This is the reason I was getting the error: You are getting that error because master..xp_cmdshell requires/ supports @cmd input with size either Varchar(8000) or varchar(4000)..

It will not allow more thatn 8000 characters                 
 Referece:   https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24999178/Problems-using-varchar-max-in-Query.html

Comment: @softgi Ah yes, I didn't get to execute on my test database... Good find :).